# How can I filter this dynamic object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I filter this dynamic object in javascript?
For the below data object is dynamic, I want to filter if the page is same but hasPlan is false.

```
   data = [ { page: 1, hasPlan: false },
      { page: 2, hasPlan: false },
      { page: 3, hasPlan: false },
      { page: 4, hasPlan: false },
      { page: 4, hasPlan: true },
      { page: 5, hasPlan: false },
      { page: 6, hasPlan: false } ];
```

expected result:

```
 data = [ { page: 1, hasPlan: false },
          { page: 2, hasPlan: false },
          { page: 3, hasPlan: false },
          { page: 4, hasPlan: true },
          { page: 5, hasPlan: false },
          { page: 6, hasPlan: false } ];
```

Comment: what happens if you have several and all false `hasPlan` for the same page?

Comment: ... or for that matter duplicate pages all with `hasPlan=true`

Answer (score 0):

First make a map

```
map = {};
data.forEach( function(item){ 
   map[ String(item.page) ] =  map[ String(item.page) ] || item.hasPlan; //notice that if map[ String(item.page) ] is already true, then item.hasPlan is not set.
});
```

Then iterate the same map and get the output

```
var output = Object.keys(map).map( s => ({ page : s , hasPlan : map[s] }) )
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = [ { page: 1, hasPlan: false },
      { page: 2, hasPlan: false },
      { page: 3, hasPlan: false },
      { page: 4, hasPlan: false },
      { page: 4, hasPlan: true },
      { page: 5, hasPlan: false },
      { page: 6, hasPlan: false } ];
var map = {};
data.forEach( function(item){ 
   map[ String(item.page) ] =  map[ String(item.page) ] || item.hasPlan;
})
var output = Object.keys(map).map( s => ({ page : s , hasPlan : map[s] }) );

console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get first an object with all `hasPlan` pages and then filter the data.

```js
var data = [{ page: 1, hasPlan: false }, { page: 2, hasPlan: false }, { page: 3, hasPlan: false }, { page: 4, hasPlan: false }, { page: 4, hasPlan: true }, { page: 5, hasPlan: false }, { page: 6, hasPlan: false }],
    hasPlan = {},
    result;

data.forEach(function (o) {
    if (o.hasPlan) {
        hasPlan[o.page] = true;
    }
});

result = data.filter(function (o) {
    return !hasPlan[o.page] || o.hasPlan;
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES6

```js
var data = [{ page: 1, hasPlan: false }, { page: 2, hasPlan: false }, { page: 3, hasPlan: false }, { page: 4, hasPlan: false }, { page: 4, hasPlan: true }, { page: 5, hasPlan: false }, { page: 6, hasPlan: false }],
    hasPlan = new Set(data
        .filter(o => o.hasPlan)
        .map(o => o.page)
    ),
    result = data.filter(o => !hasPlan.has(o.page) || o.hasPlan);


console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

My approch would be:

```
var data = [ { page: 1, hasPlan: false },
      { page: 2, hasPlan: false },
      { page: 3, hasPlan: false },
      { page: 4, hasPlan: false },
      { page: 4, hasPlan: true },
      { page: 5, hasPlan: false },
      { page: 6, hasPlan: false } ];

data.forEach(d => {
    if (d.hasPlan){
        data.filter(d2 => d2.page === d.page).forEach((d3, i) => {
            if(d3.hasPlan === false) {
                data.splice(data.indexOf(d3), 1);
            }
        });
    }
});
```